# Noise through HDMI output

Tags: sound, hdmi

I tried to watch some streaming video on my led TV through HDMI output of my laptop. First, I have had only video on the TV and sound was coming through laptop speakers. Normally both audio and video should come out of TV but I had to go to sound settings and chose HDMI as output and when I clicked on the test button, sound comes just as normal for a few second but after that it becomes noisy. Problem persists with YouTube videos as well so it is not video player related.

Why do you think would that happen? I hadn't have this problem with Windows.

Ubuntu version 20.04.02.

Comment: It's probably a hardware bug Go to the Activities view and open a Terminal. Run # lspci as superuser; or type # sudo lspci and enter your password. enter the root (administrator) password and then type lspci. Check if a sound driver or sound device is displayed: in that case, you should see the serial number and model of the sound card. Also # lspci -v shows a list with more detailed information. try installing the drivers for your card.

Comment: Audio device is an Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09). I searched for the drivers but neither Intel nor laptop manufacturer offers it.